# Why does scala evaluate a type alias when it has a line break and no equals sign?

Tags: scala, types, scala-repl

I notice when declaring a type alias in the REPL, a line break causes a statement to succeed:

this works:

```
scala> type a
     | 3 == 3
defined type alias a
res32: Boolean = true
```

This does not:

```
scala> type a 3 == 3              ^
       error: `=`, `>:`, or `<:` expected
```

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I added that the alias is declared but abstract, so it should say that instead of "defined". The REPL is smart enough not to import it.

Comment: Thanks, I also created a ticket because it's inconsistent https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11899

Comment: Thanks everyone, I submitted a fix for the bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's legal to have an abstract type as shown.

The REPL is in a special parsing mode where it knows if the current line is a complete syntax production or if more input is required, so that's why it goes to a second line, even though technically it should just accept `type a`.

```
scala> object X { type a }
defined object X

scala> object X { def x: Int }
                      ^
       error: only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members

scala> type a
     | 42
defined type alias a
res0: Int = 42

scala> def x: Int
     | 42
           ^
       error: only traits and abstract classes can have declared but undefined members
```

The REPL doesn't import the abstract typedef into the current expression because it knows it is abstract.

The type maybe not be very useful, but it is a thing:

```
scala> object X { type a }
defined object X

scala> val x: X.a = null.asInstanceOf[X.a]
x: X.a = null

scala> def x: X.a = ???
x: X.a

scala> def x: X.a = null
                    ^
       error: type mismatch;
        found   : Null(null)
        required: X.a
```

Comment: I tried using `:paste` to get around the REPL special way of parsing. Funnily enough, typing only `type a` results in `The pasted code is incomplete! ...but compilation found no error? Good luck with that.` which, though funny, does seem like an unhandled edge-case :) (note: I only have access to a 2.11.12 REPL ATM). **EDIT**: not that that contradicts/invalidates your answer in any way.

Comment: @Marth oh man, they changed it! `No error found in incomplete source.`

Comment: @Marth sorry, I changed the text. I also deleted the excellent punning comment, `// Remembrance of Things Pasted`, if you're a fan of Proust.